# Prove the geometric series r^n for r between (-1,1) is Cauchy

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I need to prove that the series (not the sequence) of the geometric series r^n is Cauchy. This converges when r is between -1 and 1 so it's definitely Cauchy and I need to show that for any epsilon, for some N, all m,n >N the distance between the partial sums is less than epsilon. At the moment, I am not sure what the algebra is to get started to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

It conveges.  For the partial sums equal $\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\to\dfrac1{1-r}$.

And any convergent sequence is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

If $r \in (-1,1)$, then $|r| \in (0,1)$. Because $r$ is fixed, given $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose $n_{0}$ such that:
$$\frac{2|r|^{n_{0}}}{|1-r|} < \epsilon$$
Now, let $N, M > n_{0}$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $N \ge M$. Denote by $S_{N}$ the partial sum:
$$S_{N} = r^{1}+\cdots r^{N}$$
Then, we have:
$$|S_{N}-S_{M}| = |r^{M+1}+r^{M+2}+\cdots + r^{N}| = \bigg{|}\frac{r^{M+1}(1-r^{(N-M)})}{1-r}\bigg{|} = \bigg{|}\frac{r^{M+1}-r^{N-1}}{1-r}\bigg{|}$$
Because $N,M > n_{0}$, then $N-1 \ge n_{0}$ and $M+1 > n_{0}$. Moreover, because $|r| \in (0,1)$, we have $|r|^{n_{0}} \ge |r|^{N-1}$ and $|r|^{n_{0}}\ge |r|^{M+1}$. Thus, we get:
$$|S_{N}-S_{M}| \le \bigg{|}\frac{r^{M+1}-r^{N-1}}{1-r}\bigg{|} \le \frac{|r|^{M+1}+|r|^{N-1}}{|1-r|} \le \frac{2|r|^{n_{0}}}{|1-r|} \le \epsilon$$